# Incomplete URL value in MySql database?

Tags: mysql

i am trying to save a html form data into a MySql database, everything works fine apart from the **URL INPUT** ?

**HTML** :

```
<input type="url" name="website">
```

Example! :

URL : `http://download.startpagina.nl/?utm_source=download.nl&utm_medium=parkeddomains&utm_campaign=redirect`

is stored as :

`httpdownload.startpagina.nlutm_sourcedownload.nlutm_mediumparkeddomainsutm_campaignredirect`

Its missing **slashes** and all **special characters** (&,= etc)

How to fix this?

I am using **Joomla JInput** to insert data :

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$url = $input->get('website');

$db = JFactory::getDbo(); 
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$columns = array('website');
$values = array($db->quote($url));

$query->insert($db->quoteName('#__websites'))
  ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
  ->values(implode(',', $values));

$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
```

Comment: Can you show the code that is inserting this?

Comment: i am using Joomla JInput to insert data..i updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput indicates the default behaviour of `$input->get('website')` is to use the `CMD` filter, which does this:

> Allow a-z, 0-9, underscore, dot, dash. Also remove leading dots from result.

You probably want `RAW` or `STRING`.

Example : `$input->get('var_name', null, 'RAW');`

Comment: FYI, I've never used this tool, but Googling "jinput stripping characters" gave this page as the first result.

Comment: i tried `RAW` but it didn't work! i found another filter there `PATH`, i guess it will do the trick, but i couldn't understand how to implement that filter? Can you help a bit with the coding stuff?

Comment: `PATH` will **definitely** not do the trick, look at its regex. How you use it is shown right there in the docs. `$input->get('website', null, 'RAW');`